# Using Tooling API to run multiple test Synchronously

Tags: api, json, tooling-api

I am trying to use the POST methods to run some test classes.I am testing the API calls with workbench

```
/services/data/v41.0/tooling/runTestsSynchronous/
```

This body works

```
{"tests":[{"className":"TestClass1"}]}
```

This body with multiple class returns "Provide only one tests array"

```
{"tests":[{"className":"TestClass1"} , {"className":"TestClass2"} ]}
```

What I am doing wrong in the JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

runTestsSynchronous can only run a single test class

According to documentation:

> Runs one or more methods within **an** Apex class, using the
>   synchronous test execution mechanism. All test methods in a
>   synchronous test run must be in the same class.

Notice  **an** indicating singularity. That makes sense as test class take big time to execute running hundreds of test class in SYNC mode might be overkill.

That being said you can still use async test execution method.

```
 /runTestsAsynchronous/ Body: 
{"classNames":
   "***comma-separated list of class names***",
"classids":
   "comma-separated list of class IDs", 
"suiteNames":
   "comma-separated list of test suite names",
"suiteids":
   "comma-separated list of test suite IDs", 
"maxFailedTests":
   "integer value",
"testLevel":"TestLevel enum value"}
```

More info :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm

Comment: Was it the case in older API e.g v36

Answer (score 0):

I know you specified the Tooling API in your question, but long ago there was another API that has the method you require.

The Apex API was the precursor to the Tooling API and included a [`runTests()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_runtests.htm) method. With the [RunTestsRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_calls_runtests_request.htm) parameter you can specify the class names for the test you want to tun. This method is blocking and the tests will all run synchronously and produce a single debug log.

You will need to use a tool capable of calling a SOAP API to utilize this method.